# Maximum Likelihood Classification says there are 0 classes when there should be 5

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification, error-010067

I'm trying to do an image classification. I created a polygon with 5 different classes (identified in the Id column; 1-5). I then created a signature file (which took about an hour to complete). When I did the maximum likelihood classification using that sig file, it gave me an immediate error saying there are fewer than 1 class.

I set the data frame to Canada Lambert Conformal Conic. I added the scanned paper map. Added a townships shapefile. Georeferenced it using about 6 control points. Created new shapefile in ArcCatalog using Canada lambert conformal conic as the CRS. Created 3 polygons for each class, differentiating them using 1,2,3,4 or 5 in Id column. Created signature in same folder as other data. Performed MLC using that sig file but it immediately gave me that error.

How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: What were the precise steps (tools and all parameter values) that you used?

Comment: @PolyGeo I set the data frame to Canada Lambert Conformal Conic. I added the scanned paper map. Added a townships shapefile. Georeferenced it using about 6 control points. Created new shapefile in ArcCatalog using Canada lambert conformal conic as the CRS. Created 3 polygons for each class, differentiating them using 1,2,3,4 or 5 in Id column. Created signature in same folder as other data. Performed MLC using that sig file but it immediately gave me that error.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "created a polygon". Do you really mean that you created a single polygon and then created five columns for your clases? If so, this is why you are getting an error, you only have one observation.

Comment: I meant I made a polygon feature class. The ID column for each feature had a number between 1 and 5.